# Are the two lists of blocked and allowed regions accessible by YouTube API mutually exclusive?

Tags: youtube-data-api

The problem is to reach a definative unambigious conclusion regarding a given video as to:
1)If the video is blocked in the region of the originating query.
2)If yes then a list of  regions where the video is available for streaming.

Ideally this should be straight forward if the blocked and allowed lists returned through the API are mutually exclusive: Existence of a specific region in one list indicates its absence from the other. A default state would be either allowed everywhere or nowhere and the either the creator or Youtube while able speify this for any given video the the mutual exclusivity of the two lists is preserved by the managment software automatically.

Any other configuration is bound to create ambiguities unless there is an extra rule created by Youtube to be considered by the query. What would those rule(s) be?

What purpose is served by deviating from the fundemental mutually exclusivity and introducing an additional rule(s).?

I searched the documentation  and searched the web for a definative answer and I got a result that provides a sample code regarding channels but not videos that can be interpreted as to the answer to my question being yes. But I have been made aware of otherwise.

Furthermore, neither the relevant question nor the answer could be considered categorical.

Comment: Why no one seems to have a response to this question? It is straightforward.
The programmer who works for me insists that this is not the case but he can't answer of the solution for the ambiguities that may arise.
I can write a script to test a few but I honestly don't have the time and it still wouldn't answer the question. Some one from YouTube should be able to answer it.